# Can a select statement include nested result-sets?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Given the following tables and sample data:

```
create table Orders (
  ID int not null primary key, 
  Customer nvarchar(100) not null);

create table OrderItems (
  ID int not null primary key,
  OrderID int not null foreign key references Orders(ID),
  Product nvarchar(100) not null);

insert into Orders values (1, 'John');
insert into Orders values (2, 'James');
insert into OrderItems values (1, 1, 'Guitar');
insert into OrderItems values (2, 1, 'Bass');
insert into OrderItems values (3, 2, 'Guitar');
insert into OrderItems values (4, 2, 'Drums');
```

I'd like to find out if I can query the parent `Orders` table and also get the child `OrderItems` table as a nested result-set in the parent result. Something like this:

```
| ORDER.ID | ORDER.CUSTOMER | ORDER.ORDERITEMS                   |
------------------------------------------------------------------
|          |                | ORDERITEMS.ID | ORDERITEMS.PRODUCT |
|          |                |-------------------------------------
|        1 |           John |             1 |             Guitar |
|          |                |             2 |               Bass |
|        2 |          James |             3 |             Guitar |
|          |                |             4 |              Drums |
```

The query I have in mind (which doesn't work in SQL Server) is something like this:

```
-- doesn't work, but shows the intent to have nested result sets
select 
  o.OrderID [Order.ID], o.Customer [Order.Customer],
  (select 
     oi.ID [OrderItems.ID], oi.Product [OrderItems.Product] 
     from OrderItems oi where o.ID = oi.OrderID
  ) [Order.OrderItems]
from Orders o;
```

This is just a conceptual question as I'm trying to think of ways to get related data with minimum duplication (as opposed to what would happen with a `join`, for example).

SQL Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5405a/2).

**UPDATE**

I found out from [this answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/91292/21384) that Oracle supports it with cursor expressions:

```
select 
  o.*,
  cursor(select oi.* from OrderItems oi where o.ID = oi.OrderID) as OrderItems
from Orders o;
```

Comment: That would go against the relational model (in particular, 1NF, the requirement for an attribute to consist of one fact only).

Comment: Well if you need a join, you should use one.  Even if you got the subquery to work, it would be a correlated subquery which is way slower than a join (correlated subqueries run run by row and are essentially cursors and should rarley ever be in production code). Normally formatting like you show above would be done by the application not the SQL.

Comment: @HLGEM: The formatting was just to show the result I wanted. The "problem" with the `join` is that it can transfer a lot more data than necessary. Say that the `Orders` table has 200 columns, and each order has on average 10 items...

Comment: @Oded: I'm not proposing changing the model itself, just the way it's queried...

Comment: YOu don;t have to return any more columns than you want in a join, in fact you shoudl never use select * but only specify the columns you want.

Comment: @HLGEM: I completely agree!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No. This isn't really possible.

SQL Server has no support for nested relations and [NF²](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization#Non-first_normal_form_.28NF.C2.B2_or_N1NF.29)

Though you could use `FOR XML PATH` to bring it back in a hierarchical manner.

```
SELECT ID       AS [@ID],
       Customer AS [@Customer],
       (SELECT ID      AS [@ID],
               OrderID AS [@OrderID],
               Product AS [@Product]
        FROM   OrderItems
        WHERE  OrderItems.OrderID = o.ID
        FOR XML PATH('OrderItems'), TYPE)
FROM   Orders o
FOR XML PATH('Order'), ROOT('Orders')
```

Returns

```
   <Orders>
      <Order ID="1" Customer="John">
        <OrderItems ID="1" OrderID="1" Product="Guitar" />
        <OrderItems ID="2" OrderID="1" Product="Bass" />
      </Order>
      <Order ID="2" Customer="James">
        <OrderItems ID="3" OrderID="2" Product="Guitar" />
        <OrderItems ID="4" OrderID="2" Product="Drums" />
      </Order>
    </Orders>
```

This doesn't repeat the parent `Orders`